# How to resolve "Cycle inside..." build error in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, build

After migrating a project from Xcode 12.4 running Catalina 10.15.5, I'm now running Xcode 13.4.1 on Monterey 12.5.1.  Before the migration, there was no such error.

If I do `Product > Clean Build Folder`, the project builds and runs normally.  But if I initiate another build, which I'm directing to the simulator as it happens, I get the following:

> Cycle inside Cosmos; building could produce unreliable results. This usually can be resolved by moving the target's Headers build phase before Compile Sources.

When I click the top level item in the project navigator, then select the target, and then `build phases`  I'm in unfamiliar territory; I have never manually done anything in this area of Xcode.  I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score -1):

You need to not just look at the target for your own code, but also the targets from libraries that your code uses.

From `Project navigator`, select `Pods`.  You should see a target `Cosmos`.  Select that, then select `Build Phases`. You will see `Headers` and `Compile Sources`.  Drag the `Headers` entry above `Compile Sources`.  Repeat this process with any other Pods that your project uses, and this should satisfy the build process so that it no longer complains about "Cycle inside..."